# JUnit Testing assistance re logic needed

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am trying to formulate a JUnit test for the below code and I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as I am completely stumped!

```
public ArrayList<PathData> tileClicked(Coordinate tile){
    ArrayList<PathData> pathData = new ArrayList<>();
    Tile clickedTile = gameBoard.getTile(tile);
    int totalNumPlayers = clickedTile.getNumberOfPlayers();
    Player cur;
    //GuiInstruction guiInstruction = new GuiInstruction();
    //guiInstruction
    if (clickedTile.hasPort()){
        //deal with ports
        for(int j = 0; j < totalNumPlayers; j++){
            cur = clickedTile.getPlayerIndex(j);
            if(cur.equals(currentPlayer)){
                pathData = specialCalculateMove(currentPlayer, true);
            }
        }
    } else if (clickedTile.hasPlayer()){
        for(int i = 0; i < totalNumPlayers; i++){
            cur = clickedTile.getPlayerIndex(i);
            if(cur.equals(currentPlayer)){ //TODO: Is this if statement stupid? 
                pathData = normalCalculateMove(currentPlayer);
            }
        }
    }else{
        //TODO: Does this actually do anything?
    }
    return pathData;

}
```

Comment: What has you stumped?  Your question is too broad.  What do you expect to happen?   What if the tile reference that's passed in is null?  What should happen?  I see too many TODO comments that suggest you don't even understand your method, let alone the test.

Comment: Please be clear with the requirement what you need to assert and what functionality you need to test and so on .Is this method you need to test ?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty broad question, thus you only get some broad hints (not going to write code for you!):

- You have to understand A) what are parameters going into the method B) what are results resp. "observable" effects that your method can have
- From there: you provide a single tile parameter; and depending on the actual state of that object, your method under test is using different paths

That translates to: you want to have at least one "test method" for each possible path through your method. That test method calls the method under test with an argument *designed* to take a certain path. You invoke the method under test; and then you check whether the result that is returned meets your expectations.